# Deriving a power series

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, power-series, formal-power-series

I Want to find the function represented by $\sum_{k=1}^{\infty} k^2z^k$.

Here is what I have done so far:

starting with $\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}z^k = \frac{z}{1-z}$ as a definition of a geometric series. We then can take the derivative of the series and multiply it by z yielding $\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}kz^k = \frac{z}{(1-z)^2}$. Repeating this process we obtain $\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}k^2z^k = \frac{z}{(1-z)^2} + \frac{2z^2}{(1-z)^3}$.

Does the index have to change when we integrate this, or is this the final solution and nothing changes?

Comment: Derivative of $(z^1)'=1=z^0$, so the index change. $(z^0)'=1'=0$, so the index doesn't go below $k=0$.

Comment: So after the derivation the index decrements to $k=0$?

Comment: Yes in the general case, but in your case, since you are multiplying by $z$ again, it changes back to $k=1$.

Comment: Right, so in both cases then since I multiply by $z$ the index won't change.

Comment: Really I recommend trying it with the index changing as well. You'll get the same answer, you'll see that your way is better, and you'll understand both approaches more than you did before. (You can also experiment with starting from $\sum_{k=0}^\infty z^k = \frac1{1-z}$ instead of $\sum_{k=1}^\infty z^k = \frac z{1-z}$ and see what difference that makes.)

Comment: Thank you I really get that yeah!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a way to avoid this question of reindexing.

I shall make it a bit more difficult with $\sum_{k=1}^{\infty} k^3z^k$.

Write $$k^3=k(k-1)(k-2)+a k(k-1)+b k +c$$ that is to say
$$c+k (-a+b+2)+(a-3) k^2=0$$ from which $a=3$, $b=1$ and $c=0$. So
$$\sum_{k=1}^{\infty} k^3z^k=\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}k(k-1)(k-2)z^k+3\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}k(k-1)z^k+\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}kz^k$$ which can write
$$\sum_{k=1}^{\infty} k^3z^k=z^3\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}k(k-1)(k-2)z^{k-3}+3z^2\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}k(k-1)z^{k-2}+z\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}kz^{k-1}$$ that is to say
$$\sum_{k=1}^{\infty} k^3z^k=z^3\left(\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}z^k\right)'''+3z^2\left(\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}z^k\right)''+z\left(\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}z^k\right)'$$